# Remove HTML Tags in Haskell

Tags: html, haskell

I have a string such as

```
&lt;b&gt;Vitamin A&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;Chloe Braided Halter Swim Top&#44;
```

Using Text.HTML.TagSoup I am attempting to remove all html and just have

```
"Vitamin Chloe Braided Halter Swim Top"
```

using

```
import qualified Text.HTML.TagSoup as TS 
TS.parseTags "&lt;b&gt;Vitamin A&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;Chloe Braided Halter Swim Top&#44;"

[TagText "<b>Vitamin A</b><br>Chloe Braided Halter Swim Top,"]
```

How can I strip all HTML tags ?

Comment: But... there aren't any HTML tags in your original string! (And TagSoup is correctl

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be with `Text.HTML.TagSoup`? It seems `Hakyll.Web.Html` would be a much better fit: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.1.2.1/docs/Hakyll-Web-Html.html

There you have a function that does what it seems you want:

stripTags :: String -> StringSource

Strip all HTML tags from a string